# Why WCF custom ServiceHostFactory getting called every time?

Tags: wcf, wif

I have a WCF service (hosted in IIS 7.5) which has SVC file less activation using the following

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment> 
   <serviceActivations>
      <add factory="String"
           service="String"/>
   </serviceActivations>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

I am using a custom host factory not the default one.

And the service is WSTrustServiceContract. Now if you see the declaration of this class

```
[ServiceBehaviorAttribute(Name = "SecurityTokenService", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/securitytokenservice", 
    InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsAttribute(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class WSTrustServiceContract : IWSTrustFeb2005SyncContract, 
    IWSTrust13SyncContract, IWSTrustFeb2005AsyncContract, IWSTrust13AsyncContract, IWsdlExportExtension, IContractBehavior
```

So we can infer that

1. The custom host factory will be called to create instance of the service.
2. Once the service instance is created, it will be there for all the requests (InstanceContextMode.Single)

My questions are

1. Why the instance of custom host factory is getting created per call (I have a breakpoint in the constructor of this factory. I am debugging by attaching to w3wc instance) ?
2. Why instance of my service is getting created per call?

Comment: Try to check your configuration again. I tried to simulate that by creating  sample application but it worked correctly, only one instance of custom host factory and service was created.

Comment: @Lukas: What should i check in configuration?

Comment: Can you show me how your custom host factory creates the instance of that service?

Answer (score 0):

As I said, I created simple application and it worked correctly. So try to compare that:

**ServiceHost**

```
Public Class MyServiceHost
    Inherits ServiceHost

    Public Sub New(serviceType As Type, baseAddresses As Uri())
        MyBase.New(serviceType, baseAddresses)
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class MyServiceHostFactory
    Inherits ServiceHostFactory

    Public Sub New()
        Trace.TraceInformation("MyServiceHost instance created.")
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Function CreateServiceHost(serviceType As Type, baseAddresses As Uri()) As ServiceHost
        Return New MyServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses)
    End Function

End Class
```

**Service**

```
<ServiceContract>
Public Interface IService

    <OperationContract()>
    Function SayHello(name As String) As String

End Interface

<ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode:=InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode:=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)>
<AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode:=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)>
Public Class Service
    Implements IService

    Public Sub New()
        Trace.TraceInformation("Service instance created.")
    End Sub

    Public Function SayHello(name As String) As String Implements IService.SayHello
        Trace.TraceInformation("Calling Service.SayHello({0}).", name)
        Return "Hello " & name
    End Function

End Class

Public Class Global_asax
    Inherits HttpApplication

    Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Trace.TraceInformation("Application started")
    End Sub

End Class
```

**Web.config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
        <serviceActivations>
            <add factory="FileLessActivationWithCustomServiceHost.MyServiceHostFactory"
                 service="FileLessActivationWithCustomServiceHost.Service" 
                 relativeAddress="Service.svc"/>
        </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
</system.serviceModel>

<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
        <listeners>
            <remove name="Default" />
            <add name="Default"
                 type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                 initializeData="log.svclog" />
        </listeners>
    </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

I started web application, made several calls of `SayHello` function and as you can see bellow, it behaves correctly:
[image]

Comment: Your code is perfect and it will work fine. In my case i am not using a normal service contract. It is WSTrustServiceContract and it is configured in the config file as well.